# ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier ERROR In oracle

Tags: java, oracle

This is the Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demo_member")

public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "Employee_DepartmentId")
    private String EmployeeDepartmentId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmployeeDepartmentId(){
        return EmployeeDepartmentId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDepartmentId(String employeeDepartmentId) {
        this.EmployeeDepartmentId = employeeDepartmentId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +'\''+
                ",EmployeeDepartmentId="+EmployeeDepartmentId+
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the SQL code snippet:

```
create table demo_member1(
id number primary key ,
first_Name VARCHAR2(50),
last_Name varchar2(50),
age number,
Employee_DepartmentId varchar2(50)
);
```

I have oracle database connection. This is the error I get:

```
2020-07-18 12:25:02.138 ERROR 11610 --- [nio-8700-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE0_"."EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier

2020-07-18 12:25:02.162 ERROR 11610 --- [nio-8700-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE0_"."EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `Employee_DepartmentId != EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID` !

Comment: Please post the code that throws that error.

Comment: Table name demo_member but in SQL I see demo_member1. It looks like your class uses the wrong table.

Comment: there are two errors: employee_depeartment_id in Oracle, and in Java it is employee_departmentid . both are not equal. Also the table you are using in your class demo_member1 is not the same as the one using in Java, which is demo_member.

Comment: There must be some typo mistake you are doing apart from the mistakes mentioned in comment already , just check twice in cool mind and you will get it:).. however one hint ( in case you already know ignore it) look after the standard naming conventions both in Java and Oracle side. It makes the code beautiful. Cheers!!